# Update нескольких столбцов по условиям

Tags: sql, sql-server

Необходимо, что бы в результате получилось (1, 2, 1), но у меня получается (1, NULL, 1), т.к. Он не запоминает промежуточные update

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE(id INT, v1 int, v2 int)
DECLARE @t2 TABLE(id INT, t INT, v INT)

INSERT INTO @t1
VALUES
(1, NULL, NULL)

INSERT INTO @t2
VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(1, 2, 2)

UPDATE t1
SET
    v1 = IIF(t2.t = 2, t2.v, v1),
    v2 = IIF(t2.t = 1, t2.v, v2)
FROM @t1 AS t1
JOIN @t2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id

SELECT * FROM @t1
```

Это тестовый пример. В реальной таблице 26 столбцов и писать 26 update не хотелось бы.

Comment: сначала напишите такой select что бы он для одного id дал ровно одну строку. потом этот запрос уже джоините в update. В текущий момент вообще не ясно каково должно быть поведение, ведь порядок строк в SQL не определен и значит две строки с одним id могут придти в любом порядке и привести к разным результатам

Comment: *Он не запоминает промежуточные update* Никто ничего и не запоминает, да и не обязан. ЕМНИП любая запись в UPDATE обновляется только один раз - даже если имеется несколько соответствий в источнике.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то надо из таблицы T2 в зависимости от поля t поместить значения столбца v в соответствующее поле таблицы T1. Верно?
я предлагаю сначала развернуть строки в столбцы с помощью PIVOT и потом выполнить update

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE(id INT, v1 int, v2 int)
DECLARE @t2 TABLE(id INT, t INT, v INT)

INSERT INTO @t1
VALUES
(1, NULL, NULL)

INSERT INTO @t2
VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(1, 2, 2),
(2, 1, 5),
(2, 2, 6),
(3, 1, 7);

WITH pre AS(
select
id,[1],[2]
from
(select id,t,v from @t2) src
PIVOT
(
MAX(v)
FOR t IN ([1],[2])
) p
)
--select * from pre
UPDATE
t1
SET
    v1 = [1],
    v2 = [2]
FROM
@t1 AS t1
JOIN pre ON pre.id = t1.id

SELECT * FROM @t1
```

если раскомментировать строку select * from pre, то можно посмотреть результат разворачивания строк в столбцы.

Кстати, в T2 в строке t=1, стоит значение v=2. А где t=2, v=2. И, если я правильно понял задачу, в итоге будет вывод:

| 1 | 1 | 2 |

а не

| 1 | 2 | 1 |